# Pre build event fails after VSTS update

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

After the update of VSTS  yesterday our Visual Studio Pre Build Events fails.

We're doing a file copy from the source folder to the build folder of VSTS. For some reason after yesterdays update we now get an Access Denied error and the build fails.

```
copy "$(ProjectDir)Web.config" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).config"
```

> copy "C:\a\1\s\Source\ProjectName\ProjectName\Web.config"
>   "C:\a\1\s\Source\ProjectName\ProjectName\bin\ProjectName.dll.config"
>   2016-08-18T06:10:46.9209275Z   Access is denied.
>   2016-08-18T06:10:46.9209275Z           0 file(s) copied.

(The reason we copy Web.config is to get around an issue with Assembly redirects and Azure Web Roles, found here [Azure WebRoles and configs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2014/05/15/webrole-entry-point-and-config-file/).)

The same problem occurs when we do file copies in gulp tasks into the same target directory.

We use the Hosted Build Agents.

Anyone know how to get around this issue?

[VSTS update 17 Aug](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2016-aug-17-vso)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. Changed to use the following command in pre build event.

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)Web.config" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName).config" /R /Y
```

It seems that they have made some changes to file access rights since the last update.

Since the last update on VSO all source files are now readonly.